# What is the difference between "invasion" and "intrusion"?

Tags: meaning, etymology, latin

What is the difference between "invasion" and "intrusion", according to the original latin meaning?

Comment: Hi, welcome to EL&U. Please include some details in the question such as "examples that make you confused with either of the two nouns, or any sentnece you find wrong. It will be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the dictionary, *intrude* is from Latin trudo = thrust, and *invade* is from Latin vadere = go.

This doesn't help much with understanding the usage of the two words. *Invade* primarily means to enter another country with an army, but we might also say: "Pardon this intrusion. I don't want to invade your privacy". Generally, an intrusion is polite while an invasion is more violent.